# Why must I use $("ssh-agent") everytime I want to pull/push from a git remote repository?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, git, ssh-agent

Each time I want to pull or push to a remote Gitlab repository, it gives me the following error:

**> sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation

> Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.**

I have tried to deal with this error, and the only way I found to solve it, but temporarely, is to use the command:

**> eval $("ssh-agent")**

The problem is that each time I want to push/pull to Gitlab, I must use this command, which is not normal.

Why is this and how can I definitely solve it ?

PS: I'm in ubuntu 16.04.6. and I am sure I added my ssh-key to Gitlab correctly.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I have the exact same question...

Answer (score 1):

You might have not added your private key to the ssh agent.
To do so use these commands:

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: What does this solve? He's already doing this. The question is about how to avoid doing this everytime.